# Display a text string and change it dynamically Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, text

Basically what i want to do is to display a name taken from a file that contains many others, and after a small delay, the given name changes into another word. The text that i wanna change is inside a `Text()` widget.

```
class ReadTextFile extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReadTextFile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ReadTextFileState createState() => _ReadTextFileState();
}

/*
 *  Retriving data from file, picking a random word and assign it to dataFromFile
 */

class _ReadTextFileState extends State<ReadTextFile> {

  String dataFromFile = "";
  static List<String> listOne = []; //contains all jobs.txt content, from top to bottom
  int randomIndex = Random().nextInt(1027); //quick fix to "RangeError" thrown by Random().nextInt(listOne.length)

  Future<void> readText() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/jobs.txt');
    listOne = response.split(',');
    setState(() {
      dataFromFile = listOne[randomIndex];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    readText();
    // showRandomJob();
    return Container(child: Center(child: Text(dataFromFile)));
  }
}
```

Widget tree:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'ListGenerator';

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          foregroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 32, 75, 132),
          title: Text(appTitle),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 11, 161, 242),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: const[
             Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: ReadTextFile(),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
 
}
```

As a plus, i'd like to know why passing  `listOne.length` as a parameter to `Random.nextInt()` generates these 2 errors.

After running a hot restart:

```
RangeError (max): Must be positive and <= 2^32: Not in inclusive range 1..4294967296:
0
See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors
```

Running a hot reload after a hot restart:

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 6205 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true. See also: https//flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors
```

Comment: Is the text not changing? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readText()` is a Future method, you need to await before using its data. Next thing is we can't tell what should be the response list. We need to act based on list items.

```dart
class _ReadTextFileState extends State<ReadTextFile> {
  String dataFromFile = "";
  static List<String> listOne = [];

  Future<void> readText() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/jobs.txt');
    listOne = response.split(',');

    int c = 0;
    if (listOne.isEmpty) return;
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (c == listOne.length - 1) {
        timer.cancel();
        return;
      }
      if (c != 0) dataFromFile += ",";
      dataFromFile += listOne[c];
      c++;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void initData() async {
    await readText();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Center(child: Text(dataFromFile)));
  }
}
```

Comment: fine solution, but the output is the same as my previous code. (much cleaner though :) ). What I wanted to do is to, literally, update the content of the Text() widget continuosly. I'll try to be more clearer: 

Imagine hello.txt containing 4 words, "i","you","he","she". At first, i should see on screen "i", then after a small delay i should see "i, you", after another small delay "i,you,he" and so on until the file length is reached.  Knowing that Text() is immutable and iniState() can only be called once, how do i make a dynamic widget which updates itself in realtime?

Comment: In that case you can use `Future.delayed` or `Timer.periodic`

Comment: More about [Timer.periodic](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html)

Comment: It works, finally. Now, let me assure i understood how initState works: whatever you put inside it, is the nature of that widget and if you try to modify the given widget, nothing is nothing to happen. Is there anything else i should know about it? i'm a beginner with flutter, so.. :)

Comment: You can check about [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) and [Future doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) and [yt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Timer()` inside the `initState` and move the `randomIndex` line inside the `readText()` function

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ReadTextFile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ReadTextFileState createState() => _ReadTextFileState();
}

class _ReadTextFileState extends State<ReadTextFile> {

  String dataFromFile = "";
  static List<String> listOne = [];

  Future<void> readText() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/jobs.txt');
    listOne = response.split(',');
    int randomIndex = Random().nextInt(listOne.length);
    setState(() {
      dataFromFile += listOne[randomIndex]+", ";
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (val) async {
      await readText();
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Center(child: Text(dataFromFile)));
  }
}
```

Comment: your solution didn't work

Comment: I edited the solution. Try now

Comment: Thing is, Text() is an immurable widget if i'm not wrong because it is a Stateless widget. I think i should look for a stateful widget similar to Text(). By the way, i forgot to mention that i want to update the text widget but adding, after each delay, a word. Like  this: "school, job, kitchen, .." and so on.

Comment: Update the code, now the text should change periodically.